# How to make public function

Tags: function, powershell, import

I would like to define function in file functions.ps1 and then call it from another script. Something like this:

**Functions.ps1:**

```
Function Hi()
{
"hi"
}
```

Call it from another script (Call.ps1).

**Call.ps1:**

```
invoke-expression -Command .\functions.ps1
Hi
```

But function is defined in local scope of script functions.ps1 and I get err:

```
The term 'hi' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file , or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, v erify that the path is correct and try
again.
```

Is there a simple way to fix this ?

Answer (score 6):

You have to *dotsource* your script to load it into your current runspace:

```
. .\functions.ps1
Hi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this would be to dot soruce the file in the script that should use the function(s).

So in the script that will use the function put something like this.

. .\functions.ps1
Then you can start calling funcitons in that file.

A bit by memory , but think it would work.

Edit: removed a brainfart.. :)

Comment: While your answer is correct, it doesn't provide any additional information to the answer I already provided....

Comment: I dont understand the point of that comment. What is the problem with my answer.. is it correct or not? there was like 2 minutes between the two.. which just means i spent more time typing than you..

Comment: You are both right.  When you added your answer, it was legitimate, but it doesn't add anything to the other answer.

Comment: OK, I just got distracted mid sentence by a collegue didnt see that the answer got inserted in bewteen. there was no other answers when i started typing.. I mean if i had answered hours after his post.. sure. but here there was two minutes in between.. So sorry if anyones egoes got hurt while I tried to help..

Answer (score 0):

Yup, dotsource is what you're looking for.
If your script contains spaces, you would dot source it like this

```
."C:\Dotsourced script.ps1"
```

Without space, is as the other people say

```
.C:\function1.ps1
```

All the functions and logic contained in the dotsourced script will be loaded upon sourcing it. So try to keep the scripts your'e dotsourcing in functions, otherwise it will run when sourced.

Read more about it on SS64 for example:
https://ss64.com/ps/source.html